# Exercise to Heat equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am dealing with the following exercise on a generalized heat equation

Let $U$ be a open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T \in (0, \infty).$ Now, let $u$ be a solution to $$(\partial_t - \Delta ) u(x,t) = \langle  a(x,t), Du(x,t) \rangle + b(x,t) u(x,t)$$

where $a,b$ are continuous on $ \overline{U} \times [0,T].$

Furthermore, $u(x,t) = 0 $ for all$(x,t) \in \partial U \times [0,T].$

Now, I want to show that i $u(x,0) \le 0$ for all$ x \in U$ then $u(x,t) \le 0$ for all $(x,t) \in U \times [0,T].$

There are a few hints on my sheet:

1.) Let $u_{\varepsilon}(x,t) = u(x,t)-\varepsilon(t+\delta)$ where $0<\delta<(2 \max_{\overline{U}\times[0,t_0]}|b|+1)^{-1}$ then we have $u_{\varepsilon}(x,0) \le -\varepsilon \delta <0$ for all $x \in U$ (this is clear by definition).

2.) Now I am supposed to show that there cannot be a point $(x_0,t_0) \in U\times (0,\delta]$ such that

$$0= u_{\varepsilon}(x_0,t_0) = max_{\overline{U}\times[0,t_0]} u_{\varepsilon}.$$

This is where I am stuck, cause I don't see how to show this. The only thing that I noticed is that at $(x_0,t_0)$ $u_{\varepsilon}$ actuall satisfies the classical heat equation as $Du(x_0,t_0)=u_{\varepsilon}(x_0,t_0)=0.$ But this did not help me so far.

Regarding John's hint, I end up with:

$$(\partial_{t} - \Delta) u_{\varepsilon}(x,t) = \langle a, Du_{\varepsilon} \rangle +bu_{\varepsilon}(x,t)-\varepsilon(bt+b\delta-1)$$

Comment: As you pointed out, $u_\epsilon$ does not satisfy the heat equation everywhere.  I've removed my suggestion.

Comment: @muaddib thank you for clarifying this

Comment: Hint: $u_\epsilon$ satisfies some PDE (very similar to that of $u$). Can you derive that?

Comment: @John well, $(\partial_{t} - \Delta) u_{\varepsilon}(x,t) = \langle a, Du_{\varepsilon} \rangle +(b+\varepsilon)u_{\varepsilon}(x,t)-\varepsilon(t+\delta)(b+\varepsilon)$ something like this?

Comment: Well, actually I got something like $$(\partial_t - \Delta) u_\epsilon = \langle a, Du_\epsilon\rangle + bu_\epsilon + \epsilon (b(t+\delta) -1)$$

Comment: @John you are right, I see my mistake. how shall I continue?

Comment: Now at $(x_0, t_0)$, if $u_\epsilon$ attains maximum ($=0$), then try to show that the LHS is $\ge 0$, while RHS is $<0$. (Thus the equation cannot be satisfied).